# How can I view the total disk space taken up by all operating systems?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a dual boot system with windows and Ubuntu (trusty). Now, when I am in Ubuntu, I can see the disk space I have, which is 25.7 GB. It also tells me that I have 1.8 GiB of  memory.Is this the amount of memory left in the disk? And how can I see the total disk space available on my hard drive that is the total space taken up by all the operating systems?
(Note-When I boot my computer apart from Windows and Ubuntu there is also a section in the Grub menu that says:previous versions of linux, along with some complex version numbers. I don't know if this is naturally available or is a specific feature on my computer,since I was not around when my computer was first set up with Ubuntu.If more details are required about the Grub menu and it's options, then please tell me so via a comment )

Answer (score 1):

The entire disk space usages are visible irrespective of which OS you are using. Each OS provide disk utilities to provide the details.

If you are in Ubuntu - then you can use the common Unix commands -

`df -h` - To see all the mounted partitions.

`fdisk -l` - To all the Disk partition on top of you HDD.

you can learn more about `fdisk` which is very powerful tool.

Regarding the GRUB menu issue - The multiple Linux Kernel version will be displayed. Which is actually asking the user to pick which kernel version to use to boot the machine. By default grub use the latest version. If you uninstall old version then you won't see the extra entries on the grub.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu there is a tool called Disc Usage (baobob). This tool neatly lines up your partitions and used space on each partition. This will also work for the Windows partition, after you have mounted it (easiest way to do this is to just open the folder of the partition).

The 1.8 GB of memory, is probably the amount of RAM you got.

Grub has entries for your current linux kernel, previous linux kernels used, memtests and any other Operating Systems found, like Windows. So your setup would look like this.

1. Current Linux OS and current newest kernel
2. Advanced options (which lists the previous kernels used by the system)
3. Any other Linux distros you might have installed
4. Windows Boot Loader partition (if Windows 7 or newer)
5. Your Windows

The Advanced version is for when your current kernel brakes your system in some way, you can boot a previous kernel from this option and make changed so the current kernel will work. This option is rarely used these days, because of the extensive kernel testing being done, before they are release, but it is still a good thing to have, just in case.